# How to stop a fixed sidebar from occluding content when zooming in?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a fixed sidebar for a table of contents (TOC) on a website (i.e. one that stays in the same place as the user scrolls up/down).

I'm doing so using the following code in HTML:

[image]

and in CSS:

[image]

My attempt was inspired by the following tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown_sidenav.asp

While it looks fine on 100% zoom in Chrome, when I zoom in, the sidebar begins to occlude/hide/overlap some of the content adjacent to it, as illustrated below:
[image]

Anyone know how I can fix/resolve this such that the table of content behaves properly when zooming?

Comment: Cause it's what `position: fixed` does.

Comment: @ulou Is it possible to make a fixed sidebar without using "position: fixed;" then?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use percentage width here. Example:

```css
div.toc {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  ...
}
```

Zooming in modifies `px`, `em` and `rem` values, but percentages are always the same.

Answer (score 0):

#### Handle `max-width`

Try setting a `max-width` for your sidebar using `vw` ([viewport width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#numbers_lengths_and_percentages)).

*This unit is not affected by the zoom variation.* (as `%`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax`, and [others](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#numbers_lengths_and_percentages))

> This way, you can keep setting your Sidebar width in `px` or whatever CSS unit you need, but limiting the max value, based on the absolute screen width.

*For example*

```
width: 100px;        // Your default width
max-width: 25vw;     // Max absolute width (not affected by zoom)

// The zoom changes the element width
//  but will never be larger than the 25% of your screen width (25vw)
```

> Of course, you can also specify different `max-width` values for different screen sizes using some [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).
> *If instead* you prefer that the width of your Sidebar is of a constant width (in screen percentage), you can use `vw` directly in your `width` (without the need for a `max-width`).

---

*Generally*

> Keep in mind which CSS units are affected by the zoom when you choose one.

Answer (score 0):

A fixed position element does not affect the position of other elements:

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.
>
> -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed

To overcome this behavior you simply need to set the `div.contents`'s `padding-left` equal to whatever value is set for the `width` of `div.toc`. It looks like you are familiar with CSS variables, and I suggest using one in this case.

```css
body {
  --toc-width: 30vw;
  --toc-background: red;
}

div.contents {
  /* offset contents by toc width */
  padding-left: var(--toc-width);
}

div.toc {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: var(--toc-width);
  background-color: var(--toc-background);
}
```

```html
<div class="contents">
  <div class="toc"></div>
  <h1>not toc</h1>
</div>
```